# Wordpress - One page navigation

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress, url, permalinks

I'm a complete Wordpress newbie so maybe my question is like super dumb.
I installed a Wordpress and a theme, (works well).
This theme is a static one page navigation with one main top menu.
[image: Very classic]

When you click on the contact button, it scrolls all the way down with a nice parallax effect (it was in the theme). The thing is, it only works with CONTACT and HOME (the first one).
I tried everything, there's no differences in the page settings, they're all templates issued, with a navigation ID that is the same as what is in the menu.

The only difference there is is that when I click on CONTACT or HOME the URL stays the same *http://website.com* . **BUT** when I click on the other ones (those that dont work) the URL become this :  *http://website.com/#slug* .

I get that this is what makes the difference but I have no idea how to change that.

Edit : If I download the demo content of the theme it works great without changing anything.

Save me :p.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: What theme are you using? It sounds like you will need to add a class to the sections that are not working.

Comment: http://website.com/#slug  means the page header link wants to go to an `ID` section on that page if the section doesnt have an `id` called `slug` it wont work.

Comment: @Coffeebean Hi and thank you. The thing I dont get is I didn't change anything and the demo template works without any change.

Comment: @Ylama Thx Ylama, the thing is, it seems (to me) that the sections exists with the right id. But maybe I didn't set the id in the right place, is it in pages settings ?

Comment: @tinkz Without knowing what theme you are using I can't help you any further. All themes are different.

Comment: ill post an answer how it should look, if it looks like it and not working im not sure whats worng

Comment: @coffeebean The theme name is October

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`website.com/#slug` means the page header link wants to go to an ID section on that page if the section doesnt have an id called slug it wont work.

Example.

```css
.height {
min-height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#section1">header</a> <br> <a href="#section2">content</a> <br> <a href="#section3">bottom content</a> <br> <a href="#section4">footer</a>

<div class="height" id="section1">header (the divs could be anything from p tags to a tags, form tags...)</div>
<div class="height" id="section2">content</div>
<div class="height" id="section3">bottom content</div>
<div class="height" id="section4">footer</div>
```

should be something like this... So your menu has to link to the correct section id. Then it should work.

Comment: Thank you, 
This is what I get (I copied 2 lines of this menu) :

<li id="menu-item-251" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-251"><a href="#team">EQUIPE</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-252" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-252"><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>

And one of those lines work and the other does not.
And the id is matching the page id.
Where would you go on Wpress to check the id ?

Comment: Wait wait, you were right.
In wordpress editor, the id is matching, but when i inspect HTML sources, the divs id doesn't match the menu's hrefs. so you were right, but where should I change the id ? In the menu or in the html ?

Comment: try adding the url menu maybe  `www.example.com/#team`